# 500 Internal Server Error non ascii characters

Tags: ckan

when i'm trying look onto harvest job log i get

```
500 Internal Server Error
The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

An error occurred: ['ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 27-28: ordinal not in range(128)]
```

Have you met this issue?

Apache error log:

```
[Wed Apr 23 11:47:25 2014] [error] 2014-04-23 11:47:25,862 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /harvest/geoportalcr/job/last render time 1.455 seconds
[Wed Apr 23 11:47:25 2014] [error] 2014-04-23 11:47:25,947 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /harvest/geoportalcr/job/last render time 0.082 seconds
[Wed Apr 23 11:47:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=9861): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Wed Apr 23 11:47:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Wed Apr 23 11:47:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=9861): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Wed Apr 23 11:47:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Wed Apr 23 11:47:27 2014] [error] 2014-04-23 11:47:27,414 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/cs_CZ render time 0.002 seconds
```

CKAN log:

```
2014-04-23 11:47:25,862 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /harvest/geoportalcr/job/last render time 1.455 seconds
2014-04-23 11:47:25,947 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /harvest/geoportalcr/job/last render time 0.082 seconds
2014-04-23 11:47:27,414 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/cs_CZ render time 0.002 seconds
```

Comment: It seems your server was scanned for some specific exploits and/or connection attempt for a non-HTTP protocol was made. If this is Internet and this wasn't your client, better is to ignore such case.

Comment: I think, this is not the reason. Maybe something in CKAN python source is not good detecting UTF-8 encoding and trying use ASCII. But where?

Comment: We need the full traceback to determine whether this is a bug. This would be in your CKAN log file, somewhere like `/var/log/apache2/ckan_default.error.log`

Comment: I have added logs in first post.